# Permissions.Insert.setSendNotificationEmails(false) does not work anymore?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I have been using the feature of preventing notification emails when transferring ownership of files using Google Drive Java API. It has worked nicely but now recently the notification started to appear. Has something changed why the API does not work anymore. Is there a way to block the emails in some other way or what to do here?

The code snippet looks like this, where I disable notification emails:

```
Insert insert = service.permissions().insert(fileId, newPerm);
insert.setSendNotificationEmails(false);
newPerm = insert.execute();
```

I have tested with AppEngine 1.9.4 & 1.9.5 and also several Drive API versions 1.16, 1.17 and also latest 1.18-rc

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: This has now been fixed.

Yes, this is a change in behavior from a recent change push that is independent of API version. At this time there isn't any workaround that will let you both transfer ownership and not send an email.

The Drive SDK team is aware of it and are investigating how to put in a better solution right now. Unfortunately we can't give you an ETA yet.

Comment: Hi Dan! Thanks for the quick reply. Good to have clarification to this. It would be still nice to get this feature back, since there are applications where these 'forced' notifications are not useful, it just creates unnecessary email traffic, which needs to be filtered out now. Looking forward to get some solution for this, Thanks!

Comment: Hi Dan, can you elaborate this "Update: This has now been fixed."? Does it work now as before and/or does this require latest AppEngine version or latest Drive API when building the app?

Comment: Yes, Dan, can you please elaborate? My testing shows that emails are still coming through. The ability to programmatically block these emails is critical, imo.

Comment: We have noticed this isn't addressed in all situations so we are still addressing that. If you still see this in say a week from now, drop another comment here.